# what is the wrong with this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, addition

***I want to know what is wrong with this function that takes array and summation it's elements***

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var sum = 0;
var arraySum = function () {
    for (var i = 0 ; i<= arr.length ; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
};
arraySum(arr);
```

Comment: The problem is with the condition. You can use `< arr.length` but I'll suggest you to use `forEach` to iterate over array elements.

Comment: You're passing an argument, but the function doesn't have any parameters? Also, you should move the `sum` declaration (and especially the initialisation!) inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an element outside of the array, this returns `undefined`.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i<= arr.length ; i++) {
//                 ^ the equal sign
```

replace it with

```
for (var i = 0 ; i< arr.length ; i++) {
```

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var sum = 0;
var arraySum = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
};

arraySum(arr);
document.write(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there with your for loop's condition. Use `<` when you are checking against the length,

```
 for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
 //------------------^ replaced the <= with <
```

Your loop will iterate additionally one time, at that time the value will be `undefined`.

So `sum + undefined = NaN`.

If you want to use `<=` for sure then subtract 1 from the length and use it.

```
 for (var i = 0 ; i <= arr.length-1  ; i++) {
 //------------------------------^ decrement the length by 1
```

Or you can do the entire process with `Array.prototype.reduce`

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => { return a + b }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var sum = 0;
arr.forEach(function(element) {
    sum += element;
});
console.log(sum);
```